# How to get business and technology only news from NewsApi in python?

Tags: python, newsapi

I am trying to get a list of the top business/technology headlines using NewsApi in Python using this function:

```
def get_customized_news(phrase, n_news=15,pageAmount=30):
    articles = newsapi.get_top_headlines(q=phrase,
                                  language="en",
                                  page_size = n_news,
                                  page=pageAmount,
                                  sources=NewsApiClient.get_sources(category='business,technology',language='en'))
    print(articles['articles'])
```

However when doing so I would mostly get null results after typing simple phrases such as "Blackrock" or "Apple stock" and when replacing top headlines with the get_everything function I simply just get irrelevant results despite specifying the domains I want to use. How would I be able to get relevant, top headlines from pythons newsapi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like the main problem you're having is with this line:
`sources=NewsApiClient.get_sources(category='business,technology',language='en'))`

1. NewsApiClient.get_sources fails with a TypeError when I call it as its missing the parameter `self` (needs to be called as an instance method)
2. As far as I can tell in the documentation, if you're using categories, you can only pass in a single category.
3. Even if you fixed that call, get_sources returns a dictionary (or more likely JSON), which contains a list of dictionaries of metadata for all the sources, while the `sources` parameter needs to be a comma delimited list of only the source ids; for example `sources="bbc-news,wired"`

I ran the following with success:

```
from newsapi import NewsApiClient
from pprint import pprint

newsapi = NewsApiClient(api_key = SECRET_API_KEY)

def get_customized_news(phrase, category, n_news=15,pageAmount=1):
    articles = newsapi.get_top_headlines(q=phrase,
                                  language="en",
                                  page_size = n_news,
                                  page=pageAmount,
                                  category=category)
    pprint(articles['articles'])

get_customized_news("Apple", "business", 10, 1)
get_customized_news("Apple", "technology", 10, 1)
```